# Entity Framework code first : delete all records in localdb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, localdb

Is there a way to remove all records from all the tables? I do integration testings and want to drop and recreate the data after each test!

I don't use any special tests library, only Microsoft fakes.

Thanks.

Comment: I like to use the [Respawn library](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/02/19/reliable-database-tests-with-respawn/) by Jimmy Bogard (author of AutoMapper)

Answer (score 1):

You could drop and recreate the entire database.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
```

You can also override DropCreateDatabaseAlways if you need to seed the database after it is recreated.

Comment: I use it, but it only drops at the first run of the database. I want to drop after each test

Comment: I imagine you are probably pretty far along implementation but I would really recommend trying to make your integration tests data independent.  So seed the database with the static look up type data and let each integration test build its own setup data.  Trying to share transactional data between tests is a problem waiting to happen.  Autofixture is a nice library that will automate the task of generating fake-ish data in your objects so you don't have to go through that for every test.

Comment: I implmement a seed method and want each test to run independently, that's why I'm trying to delete all the data after test in TestCleanup and recreate again in TestInit

Comment: did you find a solution to this?